# What is correct: "multiple restrike" or "multiple restrikes"? In general: should a noun after "multiple" be in singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is correct: "multiple restrike" or "multiple restrikes"? In general: should a noun after "multiple" be in singular or plural? (One "restrike" or more "restrikes" after each other can appear in circuit-breakers when breaking small capacitive currents.)

Comment: Has to be plural - 'multiple restrikes'.

Comment: Hi WS2, you may not be aware that a "multiple restrike" system is an engineering thing.  Google eg. "multiple restrike car ignition" or "multiple restrike capacitor" etc.

Comment: That being said, Zdenek may indeed be referring to the "things" restrikes, and many of them!  :)

Answer (score 2):

*Multiple* should be followed by a plural and not a singular noun if you are referring to several copies of an object. For example:

> Multiple buildings were damaged in the explosion.

Comment: If Zdenek is referring to the "things" restrikes, and he is saying to his colleague for example **"Look at that! So many restrikes! Multiple restrikes!"** then yes it is "s".  If Zdenek is (as one would expect) referring to the "things" say capacitors, and he is using the commonplace compound adjective "multiple-restrike" (which is just like "multiple-choice" or "multi-engine") then there is no "s"; it would just be **"Holy crap, we need to buy more multiple-restrike capacitors! Do they have them on amazon.com??"**

Answer (score 2):

You're forming a two-word adjective which describes something. There's no "s".

Multiple choice question.

Multiple choice questions.

Multiple choice exam.

Multiple product packaging.

Multiple seat aircraft.

Multiple restrike starter motor.

Multiple restrike fuses.

*(Hyphen korner: Note that in each case, you can use a hyphen if you want (just as with any compound).  So, for example multiple-choice exam. Makes no difference.)*

---

Note - you could make up obscure, tortured, situations where the "choice" part **IS A NOUN** and the "multiple" is just an adjective.  Something like this .. *"in life she faced multiple choices at the same time"*  or *"the lightning struck once, then restruck, then restruck again, so, we had multiple restrikes after the original strike."*   But those are just silly, of course.

Comment: What about *Multiple strike* on its own? Couldn't you put the noun in plural then —**multiple strikes**. Multiple airlines, multiple bee stings, multiple city flights, multiple dimensions etc. Irrelevant edit. Focus on the question.

Comment: There is, exceptionally, 'multiple myeloma' where 'multiple' is an adjective (loosely, multi-faceted) rather than a quantifier.

Comment: OP's question as asked was unclear. But if it's looking for an adjective, then Fattie is correct.  multiple-restrike breaker.  If a noun, plural. Multiple restrikes occurred.  But if referring to a known or standard "situation", then the singular noun is possible: "Did multiple restrike occur?  Yes, it did."